# Factoring Trinomials

Tags: polynomials

I've been working with Trinomials recently, but I ran across a problem like this: Factor the polynomial: $m^2 - mv - 56v^2$.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Observe:
\begin{align*}
m^2-mv-56v^2&=m^2-8mv+7mv-56v^2\\
&=m(m-8v)+7v(m-8v)
\end{align*}